# Google Cloud Firestore Triggers not Detecting Write to Database

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

OS: Mac OS Catalina v 10.15.1

Python version: Python 3.7.1

I'm writing a Cloud Functions in Python to be triggered by writes/updates/etc. to a Firestore database. My function essentially just looks like this in my `main.py`:

```
def hello_firestore(data, context):
    """ Triggered by a change to a Firestore document.
    Args:
        data (dict): The event payload.
        context (google.cloud.functions.Context): Metadata for the event.
    """
    print("Hello")
```

I want this function to watch for updates to the document `test_collection/test_document`. I deployed this function using:

```
gcloud functions deploy hello_firestore \
  --runtime python37 --trigger-event providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.write \
  --trigger-resource projects/PROJECT_ID/databases/default/documents/test_collection/test_document
```

The function deploys successfully, and appears in my Firebase console and in the GCP console. I have a script running on my local machine:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore
import time

cred = credentials.Certificate("./path/to/adminsdk.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
db = firestore.client()

doc_ref = db.collection(u'test_collection').document(u'test_document')
doc_ref.set({u'test_field':'test_value'})

time.sleep(60)

doc_ref.update({u'test_field':'new_value'})
```

The database updates accordingly. I expect the function to execute (since the trigger condition is satisfied), and I would expect to see the corresponding `stdout` output in the Firestore console logs or the GCP console logs. However, there is nothing there -- no error message, and no indication of the trigger event happening (the only logs are the ones that arise as a result of deploying the function). Additionally, manually editing the database in the Firestore console does not have an effect.

I've also tried writing this Cloud Function in Node.js (and deploying it accordingly) and the result is the same -- no indication that the event has occurred.

Any tips/suggestions would be great. Thanks!

Comment: I think you may have an error in the `--trigger-resource`, according to [this document](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/cloud-firestore#deploying_your_function), default should be in parenthesis. That may be the reason why your trigger is not firing since it can't find the resource

Comment: @rsalinas This gives me `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token '('`

Comment: Never mind, forgot to escape the path using single quotes. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want the following deploy command, where `default` is in parenthesis:

```
gcloud functions deploy hello_firestore \
  --runtime python37 --trigger-event providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.write \
  --trigger-resource projects/PROJECT_ID/databases/(default)/documents/test_collection/test_document
```

See here for more details: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/cloud-firestore

Comment: Trying to run the above command gives me `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('`

Comment: Ah never mind, forgot to escape the path using single quotes. Thanks!